# Are these two function independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have these 2 functions expressed as follow:
$$ H = X/(1+Y) $$
and
$$ G = Z(X+Y) $$

Are these two functions independent? If not, then why it is claimed that:
$$ F_{min(H,G)} = 1-(1-F_H)(1-F_G) $$ 
where $F_{min(H,G)}$ is the CDF of min(H,G) and $ F_H, F_G $ is the CDF of H and G, respectively.

*You can find those functions in the paper: "Interference Aided Energy Harvesting in Decode-and-Forward Relaying Systems" of Yanju Gu and Sonia A¨ıssa, where H is (5) and G is (9) (but I have simplified them). And the claim can be seen through (15)-(16). 
Sorry, but I can't find the link to the paper, but here are some notes from it:
$$\gamma_{SR}= \gamma_h/(1+I_R)$$ is (5) and
$$\gamma_{RD}= \gamma_g(\gamma_h+I_R)$$ is (9) 
and the (15) - (16) are:
$$ 
C = ... - 1/(2ln2) \int_0^\infty 1/(1+\gamma)[F_{\gamma_{min}}(\gamma)-1]dt\ 
$$
$$ 
C = ... 1/(2ln2) \int_0^\infty 1/(1+\gamma)[1-F_{\gamma_{SR}}(\gamma)][1-F_{\gamma_{RD}}(\gamma)]d\gamma\ 
$$
where $ F_{\gamma_{min}}(\gamma) $ is the CDF of $min(\gamma_{SR},\gamma_{RD}) $ and $ F_{\gamma_{SR}}(\gamma) $, $F_{\gamma_{RD}}(\gamma)$ is the CDF of $\gamma_{SR}$ and $\gamma_{RD}$, respectively (and they are RVs having exponential distribution). $I_R$ is a RV too, but it's CDF is really complicated. 
And $\gamma_{h}$, $\gamma_{g}$ and $I_R$ are independent.
As can be seen: $F_{\gamma_{min}}(\gamma) = 1-[1-F_{\gamma_{SR}}(\gamma)][1-F_{\gamma_{RD}}(\gamma)]$. Why?*

Comment: Where is that claimed, or by whom?

Comment: You can find it in the paper: "Interference Aided Energy Harvesting in Decode-and-Forward Relaying Systems" of Yanju Gu and Sonia A¨ıssa, where H is (5) and G is (9) (but I have simplified them). And the claim can be seen through (15)-(16). As I explained below :)

Comment: are $X,Y,Z$ independent?

Comment: Yes, they are independent

Comment: OK, I edited my post. Please, any idea why it is true? And are those 2 functions are independent?

Comment: What about the exponential distribution mentioned in your "citation"? Is this part of a claim (I cannot really see one) or an assumption? I'm afraid it is quite hard (at least for me) to figure out which is which. Could it be roughly: If $X, Y, Z$ are iid. rv's with exponential distribution and $G, H$ are defined as in the OP then the cdf of $\min(G, H)$ takes the form given in the OP?

Comment: I just read the paper again, and yes, $X,Y,Z$ are i.i.d. and have identical exponential distribution. And I really don't know why $F_{min(H,G)}=1−(1−F_H)(1−F_G)$. Are $H, G$ independent?

Comment: The crucial hypothesis that X, Y, Z  are i.i.d. and have identical exponential distribution **should be included in the question**. Then, **assuming furthermore that** one should read H=X/(X+Y) instead of X/(1+Y), indeed H and G are independent because H and X+Y are (as a classical exercise, which you could try to solve, shows). To see why K=X/(1+Y) and G are **not** independent, note that K<G almost surely.

Comment: Wow, thanks "Did", you've saved me a lot :D